# MD5 generate different result between C# and Java

Tags: java, c#, md5

I have a byte array, and I want to compute the MD5 hash in java and C# separately. However, their generate very different result.

below is my C# code:

```
byte[] input = { 90, 12, 200, 139, 85, 104, 9, 202, 0, 0, 0, 0, 28, 251, 54, 201, 233, 153, 79, 1 };
MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
byte[] result = md5.ComputeHash(input);
```

It generate md5 hash: `85,126,37,15,86,254,54,94,243,185,219,84,21,17,192,153,`.

and below is the java code:

```
byte[] input = {90,12,-56,-117,85,104,9,-54,0,0,0,0,28,-5,54,-47,-23,-103,79,1};
byte[] md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(input);
```

and it results in:
`-56,-74,-89,-76,9,35,-83,-89,-73,-39,17,83,24,18,-91,-62,`

As you can see, the results are quite different. I know c# use unsigned byte,  java uses signed byte. There is no way make me believe the results are identical.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your C# and Java inputs aren't the same.

Let's try to convert the C# input to signed bytes:

```
byte[] input = { 90, 12, 200, 139, 85, 104, 9, 202, 0, 0, 0, 0, 28, 251, 54, 201, 233, 153, 79, 1 };

sbyte[] signedInput = input.Select(i => unchecked((sbyte)i)).ToArray();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", signedInput));
```

This outputs:

> 90, 12, -56, -117, 85, 104, 9, -54, 0, 0, 0, 0, 28, -5, 54, **-55**, -23, -103, 79, 1

There's a different byte here, in bold. The Java version contains *-47* at this offset.

And just to be sure, we can do a simple check using the Java version's input:

```
var javaInput = new[] { 90, 12, -56, -117, 85, 104, 9, -54, 0, 0, 0, 0, 28, -5, 54, -47, -23, -103, 79, 1 };
var javaInputUnsigned = javaInput.Select(i => unchecked((byte)i)).ToArray();
var hash = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(javaInputUnsigned).Select(i => unchecked((sbyte)i)).ToArray();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", hash));
```

This yields the same result as in the Java version:

> -56, -74, -89, -76, 9, 35, -83, -89, -73, -39, 17, 83, 24, 18, -91, -62

Comment: thanks very much. Didn't notice the input data are different